# GDB Debugging: Passing arguments using IO redirection

Tags: c, gdb

I am learning how to exploit a buffer overflow. Below is the program I am playing with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    char buffer[256];
    printf("%p\n", buffer);
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this program with: `gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack program.c -o program`
I loaded this program in gdb: `gdb ./program`
If I issue following command: `run $(python -c 'print "A" * 3000')` It will overwrite the registers as desired:

```
rbp            0x4141414141414141   0x4141414141414141
rsp            0x7fffffffd938   0x7fffffffd938
r8             0x4141414141414141   0x4141414141414141
r9             0x4141414141414141   0x4141414141414141
r10            0x4141414141414141   0x4141414141414141
```

.....
But if I give arguments to the program using IO redirection registers' values are not overwritten as desired.

fuzz.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'A' * 3000
```

I output all 'A's to file f using `fuzz.py > f`

I run the program in gdb `gdb ./program`
Now If I give a argument to program using IO redirection I get abnormal output:

```
run < f
```

I get the following error:

> Stopped reason: SIGSEGV
>   __strcpy_sse2_unaligned ()
>       at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
>   296 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.

Why I am getting this error `__strcpy_sse2_unaligned` while if I pass arguments using  `run $(python -c 'print "A" * 3000')` I will only get SIGSEGV error which I desired.

info registers:

```
rbp            0x7fffffffe4f0   0x7fffffffe4f0
rsp            0x7fffffffe3d8   0x7fffffffe3d8
r8             0x0  0x0
r9             0xf  0xf
r10            0x5d 0x5d
```

Why are the registers not overwritten by 'A's?

Q1)
Why are passing arguments in gdb using:

```
run $(python -c 'print "A" * 3000')
```

and

```
run < f
```

not equal? f is the file which contains 3000 'A's.

Q2)
What is the meaning of this error: `__strcpy_sse2_unaligned ()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking input from command line arguments, not the standard input:

```
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
```

So you should use:

```
run $(python -c 'print "A" * 3000')
```

The `<` redirection would work if you're reading from stdin, for example with `scanf`.

The `__strcpy_sse2_unaligned` SIGSEGV is caused by you trying to `strcpy` from uninitialized memory (`argv[1]`, which is actually `NULL` since it's `argv[argc]` in your case). GDB then tries to find the source for that internal function, but fails.